# how to load javascripts at the end of the page

Tags: php, javascript, html, symfony1, pageload

i have a website with a lot of js files and i have loaded them in head now. but i've heard that this is not a optimize way to do that and it's better to load them at the end of body.
how can i tell symfony to load all of my javascripts at the end of the page (not in the beginning). because of performance issues it's better to load them at the end of the page loading(after html and css has been loaded)

but how can i do that? i'm using use_javascript() function to load them. but it loads them at the top of the page in the head. is there a way to tell symfony to do that?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Open your layout file - the default one is something like that:

```
apps/frontend/templates/layout.php
```

Look for the `include_javascripts()` call. Cut & paste it at the bottom of your html, just before the body closing tag:

```
    <?php include_javascripts() ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

And voila! All your javascript files are included at the bottom of your page.

If your code is depending on some libraries (jQuery, MooTools, Prototype etc.) and you have some inline JavaScript code (quite bad practice), you will have some problems because your inline code will be outputed before the inclusion of those libraries. The filter mentioned earlier looks like a good workaround. Again you don't need it if all your code is included via the `use_javascript()` function or your JavaScript code has no dependencies.
One more thing. If you want to really optimize your code, you should make as little requests as possible. A good practice is to combine all your .js files into one, minify everything and include it in your app.

Answer (score 0):

According to the jquery documentation on .getScript() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/, you can do something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

//HTML tags ..... 

<script>
$.getScript('ajax/test.js', function(data, textStatus){
   console.log(data); //data returned
   console.log(textStatus); //success
   console.log('Load was performed.');
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For fist you need to load js with DOM or function JS,

look here for implementation http://www.gee.web.id/2016/11/solusi-blogspot-untuk-speed-leverage.html

and then to execute your jquery or javascript function you need to load all page first and than make a command function, to implementation please cek here http://www.gee.web.id/2016/11/how-to-execute-javascript-when-page-has.html